# xUbuntu: screensaver settings are missed with two monitor

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce, screensaver

I've installed xUbuntu 14.04 since 2013. Two weeks ago I've bought a new monitor, so now my pc has 2 monitors.

I'm searching for the screensaver settings, but in my `Settings Manager` there isn't:

[image: Settings Manager screenshot]

I'm sure that before I had installed the second monitor this settings were visible like [here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4gRla3rx_PM/TtTKzmqxiUI/AAAAAAAAABs/zgzPHPmK6cE/s1600/xfce-settings-manager.png).

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```